# Changing the margins of a single page while keeping the headline the same

Tags: header-footer, margins, geometry, texify

I need to print a huge figure in my latex document on one single page. I'm currently using

```
\newgeometry{left=10mm, right=10mm, top=25mm, bottom=30mm}
\begin{figure}[thb]

....

\end{figure}
\restoregeometry
```

which works nearly perfectly for me. The figures look very nice and I can also refer to the usage of `\def\svgwidth{.47\textwidth}` to place two subfigures just side by side.

The only problem I've got with this is that the header-line is also moved to the top AND expanded to the width of the page. Is there some option to keep the header of the page the same?

I already tried the package `\usepackage{changepage}` but couldn't achieve the same effect like using the changegeometry...

Edit: Thanks in advance

Comment: Not even allowed to write "Thanks" at the end of a post? Wtf is going on with this network? That it's needless to say "Hello" at the start, okay, but I still say: THANKS IN ADVANCE! omg..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to change the margins, just allow the figure to bleed into the margin

```
\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics{...}}
```

will make the image have zero size and overprint the margins without complaint.

Or for finer  control, something like

```
\hspace*{-2cm}\includegraphics{...}
```

will pull the image 2cm left into the left hand margin.

Comment: Thanks, I know `\hspace*{-2cm}` but how to do that for the right hand margin as well?

Comment: @bjoern put it on the right:-) `\includegraphics{...}\hspace*{-2cm}` (possibly with \hfill before it, or not depending o how you are positioning the image)